# display album art using mediametadataretriever

Tags: java, android, metadata, albumart

okay so I am trying to display album art for songs in my app . I am trying to do it by using Mediametadataretriever. But I am getting an IllegalStateException in line  `metaRetriver.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() );`
I understand it might be because of using an invalid path but I can't figure out what is the valid path then . I am really newbie to android app development. Can anyone help me with it ?

**PlayListActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.dell_1.myapp3;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mAudioPath;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private String[] mMusicList;

    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    byte[] art;
    ImageView album_art;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }


    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        acv();
    }

    public void acv() {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() );
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart);

    }
}
```

**activity_play_list.xml**  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#242424"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_android_building_music_player.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="The Good"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.40"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                    android:onClick="buttonAction1"/>


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="250dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/download8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerDisplay"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are playing some some in one file path and you are trying to fetch the art from external storage file path, so you should send the path to that method,

```
private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        acv(path);
    }

    public void acv(String path) {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

    }
```

And few suggestions,

- You should not use setContentView multiple time in an activity I understand you are using 2 layouts, but in that case, you should use 2 different activity.
- You playing something songs and user will not be in your app always they like to move around the application so try to use service to run the song in background

For more reference, you can get fantastic opensource app will be available in Github look into that.

Comment: Thanks , its working and thanks for your suggestions, I will work on them . thanks a lot really :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to get a thumbnail from a specific file, but you are putting in the path of the External Storage Directory. So by using

```
metaRetriver.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() );
```

You are pointing to a folder, not a specific media file. But this:

```
metaRetriver.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "yourFileName.mp3" );
```

Is more in line with what you would need.

Comment: thanks but what if I want to do it for all audio files stored in external storage ??

Comment: You would have to do it for each file. So when you retrieve that file path for the particular song to play, pass it to the acv function of yours and just use metaRetriver.setDataSource(songPath)